# np.corrcoef behavior with pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

I observe the following, using some script I built for calculating series of sums per groups:

```
In [291]: sums_per_group2
Out[291]: 
        test_group  control_group
one    4551.658544         4449.3
three  3770.712771         3430.5
two    9328.171538         8673.9

In [292]: sums_per_group2.shape
Out[292]: (3, 2)

In [293]: np.corrcoef(sums_per_group2)
Out[293]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]) 

In [294]: np.corrcoef(sums_per_group2.values)
Out[294]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [295]: sums_per_group2.values.shape  
Out[295]: (3, 2)

In [296]:   np.corrcoef(sums_per_group2.iloc[:,0],sums_per_group2.iloc[:,1])
Out[296]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.99853641],
       [ 0.99853641,  1.        ]])  

In [296]:   sums_per_group2.iloc[:,0].shape
Out[296]: (3,)

In [297]:   sums_per_group2.iloc[:,1].shape
Out[297]: (3,)
```

As you could see the shape is rigorously exact between any inputs to np.corrcoef().

Can someone help me to understand this, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to transpose `sum_per_group2` variable if you want to pass it as 2d array:

```
np.corrcoef(sum_per_group2.T)
# array([[ 1.        ,  0.99853641],
#        [ 0.99853641,  1.        ]])
```

Here is the *docs* about `x` parameter:

> x : array_like
>       A 1-D or 2-D array containing multiple variables and observations.
>       Each row of `x` represents a variable, and each column a single
>       observation of all those variables. Also see `rowvar` below.

When you pass the 2d array in, make sure the column is observation and row is variable or features; The correlation is calculated between rows. Or set `rowvar=0`:

```
np.corrcoef(sum_per_group2, rowvar=0)
#array([[ 1.        ,  0.99853641],
#       [ 0.99853641,  1.        ]])
```

---

If you don't transpose the 2d array, the method interprets row as vector, so in your first few cases, it calculates the correlation coefficients of all the combinations of the rows, since each row is length 2 vector, you get all 1 as coefficients, which would happen when you try to fit a line with two points (*always perfect fit*).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the function workings, I missed the row as a vector thing. That thus makes sense now, I was wondering why this, with a mistake, would be able to systematically yield a 1 correlation factor. But I was not thinking about my shape. Now I now I should try to change it to test better the function behavior.